# Airpods Pro 2nd gen need to be restarted every few minutes when using with Windows

Tags: windows-11, airpods-pro

Totally frustrating and obviously a windows configuration problem. I think the airpods are recently up to date, and believe me, these things have been paired and unpaired and the problem is mostly random.

There is also glitching every so often where it will drop a single audio frame and keep going. Then it eventually just sounds like it's skipping every other frame for about 10 frames or so and then goes quiet. With voicemeeter I just have re-select the output and voicemeeter re-initializes it, which brings it on again.

I never have this problem with Android or Ios with these Airpods and I use them literally all the time with my android.

This is so frustrating. I am most definitely not accusing apple of sabotage, but they've never like windows, so...

Comment: Try the solutions in [this post](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/airpods-keeps-disconnecting-windows-10/4c9940b4-ba71-4e6a-94d1-30c1ba668ce6) and let us know if they help.

Comment: It's been almost 2 hours and I just heard my first glitch because of walking away from the computer. Solution 2 in that page was what fixed it. I didn't do solution 1 (well, I did then reverted it).

Comment: I have put up an answer. If the pods remains stable, please accept the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that seems to have solved the problem came from
the article
[Airpods Keeps Disconnecting Windows 10](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/airpods-keeps-disconnecting-windows-10/4c9940b4-ba71-4e6a-94d1-30c1ba668ce6):

> - In Device Manager, look for "Bluetooth" and expand it
> - Uninstall all the devices in Bluetooth (it will prompt to restart device now but click no or restart later)
> - Once you have uninstalled all of them and Bluetooth disappeared, Restart Device and don't worry it will pick up all the bluetooth
>   drivers/devices again after restart.

Comment: In my experience, it seems like I only needed to uninstall the internal hardware devices on the laptop. Uninstalling the paired Bluetooth devices didn't seem to be necessary as they disappeared once I uninstalled the host devices.